# SQL (mysql) Query on world database

Tags: mysql

## Please assist

## the following query wont work

```
        ALTER TABLE person 
        ADD COLUMN Stay_Length VARCHAR(50);
```

```
    ALTER TABLE person 
    ADD COLUMN Time_the_person_stayed_in_the_city VARCHAR(50);
```

```
        INSERT INTO Person (Stay_Length)
        VALUES ('Short'), ('Long'),('Very Long');
        INSERT INTO Person (Time_the_person_stayed_in_the_city)
        VALUES ('Less than 20 days'), ('Between 20 and 99 days'),('Over 99 days ');
```

`        SELECT Stay_Length, Time_the_person_stayed_in_the_city,

```
     CASE Stay_Length
       WHEN <20 THEN 'Short'
       WHEN 20>=99 THEN 'Long'
       WHEN >99 THEN 'Very Long'
     ELSE 'Unknown Length of Stay'
     END AS Stay_Length
     FROM Person;`
```

Comment: you forgot the persons table, that is altered

Comment: maybe you could tell us more info, the whole table definition, which query fails and what's the error message and code

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your CASE statement as follows:

```
 SELECT Stay_Length, Time_the_person_stayed_in_the_city, 
 CASE 
   WHEN Stay_Length <20 THEN 'Short'
   WHEN Stay_Length >= 20 AND Stay_Length <=99 THEN 'Long'
   WHEN Stay_Length >99 THEN 'Very Long'
 ELSE 'Unknown Length of Stay'
 END AS Stay_Length
 FROM Person;`
```

Answer (score 0):

You case statement is wrong

```
SELECT Stay_Length, Time_the_person_stayed_in_the_city,
 CASE 
   WHEN Stay_Length <20 THEN 'Short'
   WHEN Stay_Length BETWEEN 20 AND 99 THEN 'Long'
   WHEN Stay_Length >99 THEN 'Very Long'
 ELSE 'Unknown Length of Stay'
 END AS Stay_Length
 FROM Person;
```

OR

```
 SELECT Stay_Length, Time_the_person_stayed_in_the_city,
 CASE 
   WHEN Stay_Length <20 THEN 'Short'
   WHEN Stay_Length >= 20 AND Stay_Length <= 99 THEN 'Long'
   WHEN Stay_Length >99 THEN 'Very Long'
 ELSE 'Unknown Length of Stay'
 END AS Stay_Length
 FROM Person;
```